# Line wrapping in HTML forms using Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am struggling with text fields in Flask. What I want to achieve is line wrapping in the HTML forms. I tried different suggestions that I found in related HTML-threads but without luck.

E.g., let's assume I have a simple flask app with a text field, and I want to wrap the text instead of extending to the right:

[image]

My flask app looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from wtforms import Form, TextField, validators

app = Flask(__name__)

class ReviewForm(Form):
    moviereview = TextField('My Review: ', [validators.DataRequired()])

@app.route('/')
def index():
    form = ReviewForm(request.form, csrf_enabled=False)
    return render_template('reviewform.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And the template that it should render is written like this:

`./templates/reviewform.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>


<form method=post action="/results">
  <dl>
    {{ form.review(style="padding: 0 0 100px 0; cols='5'; wrap='soft'") }}
  </dl>
  <div style='padding-left:40px;'>
      <input type=submit value='Submit' name='submit_btn'> 
  </div>
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look into TextAreaField instead of TextField  for multiline http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/fields.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TextField` is actually an `input` with `type="text"`, which itself doesn't support word wrap. The `cols` and `wrap` are not working at all. I think what you need is `TextAreaField`:

```
from wtforms import Form, TextAreaField, validators

class ReviewForm(Form):
    review = TextAreaField('My Review: ', [validators.DataRequired()])
```

This will make a `textarea` that has very good word-wrap support.